# kotlin/TypeCastException when trying to create OkHttpClient object

Tags: java, okhttp, okio

When i try to create a new OkHttpClient object an Exception get thrown

I'm using OkHttp 3.11.0 and OkIO 2.0.0-RC1.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/TypeCastException
>           at okhttp3.ResponseBody.create(ResponseBody.java:210)
>           at okhttp3.internal.Util.(Util.java:60)
>           at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.(OkHttpClient.java:123)
>           at p12.Main.main(Main.java:8)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.TypeCastException
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 4 more

Comment: Can you provide the code where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you add the kotlin stdlib and stdlib-common dependencies to your build? Looks like they're absent.

Answer (score 9):

The solution that worked for me (which is mentioned in this [github comment](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5379#issuecomment-523490784)) is to add `okhttp` library itself:

Gradle kotlin DSL:

```
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2")
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.2.2")
```

Gradle Groovy DSL:

```
testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.2.2'
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
Add [kotlin-stdlib JAR](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=a%3A%22kotlin-stdlib%22&a=kotlin-stdlib) to the build Path

Comment: In case someone hopes to use it by adding a dependency in their `build.gradle` file, this link may be of help. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that your project includes the version of `okhttp` as version `3.x.x`,
causing the `mockwebserver` to depend on the wrong version of `okhttp` which also does not yet contains the transitive dependency on `kotlin-stdlib-common`.

If you are using `Spring Boot` along with `mockwebserver` just add the following property to your pom

`<okhttp3.version>4.x.x</okhttp3.version>`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had the same problem and I added the Kotlin dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
   <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.32</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In OSGi do not use the kotlin libraries, but the kotlin bundle: 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-osgi.html